# Pygame class spawns rect and then it dissapears, how do I get it to stay?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to implement a class for a basic game. It woked without the class but now instead of spawning the "coin" it pops up and then immediatly dissapears. No idea as it's in the main loop. I have a moving "player" that works fine.

Here's my code:

```
class Coin_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        coin_1 = pygame.Rect(425, 30, 40, 40)
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, coin_1)
        pygame.display.update()

 # def coin_collect():
 #        if player.colliderect():
 #            coin_1.x = random.randint(0, 800)
 #            coin_1.y = random.randint(0, 250)
 #            pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(coin_collected))
 #            global score
 #            score += 1
 #            print(score)

coin_class = Coin_Class()

# main function loop
def main():
    score_check = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        # game speed
        clock.tick(FPS)
        # initialise pygame
        pygame.init()
        # checking all the events in pygame and looping them
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # checking quit function is pressed
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() # recognise key presses
        player_movement(keys_pressed, player) # movement function
        draw_window() # create window function
        coin_class
    main()

# runs the main file
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `pygame.init` should be the first thing after imports, don't put it in the main loop. `__init__` method is called ONCE upon instantiating the object, so when you call the class (class name + `()`). You need to define some `update` method to call in the main loop that will draw, so that it draws it each loop, also what is this: `if player.colliderect():`, I think it is missing some arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a draw method to the coin class (also class names per PEP 8 should be in `CapitalCase` not `Capital_Snake_Case` so `CoinClass`):

```py
class Coin_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coin_1 = pygame.Rect(425, 30, 40, 40)

    ...

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, self.coin_1)
```

And in the loop instead of using

```py
coin_class
```

you would now use

```py
coin_class.draw()
```

The rest can stay the same, except remove `pygame.init()` from the loop and put it somewhere at the start of the code after imports